# What type of chart is this?

Tags: graph, charts

This might not be the proper place to ask this, but I was not sure.

Have a look at the chart seen [here](http://hughsk.io/disc/).

What is the proper term for this type of chart?

Comment: Excel calls it a doughnut

Comment: perhaps a sunburst chart. common name, dont know if this is correct

Comment: @stark I didn't think doughnut charts had multiple layers?

Comment: It think it is also called 'Edward Tufte's nightmare'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library uses [D3](http://d3js.org/) and D3 refers to these charts with the name "sunburst". You can find some examples here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#sunburst-and-partition-layout